# django-q task queue: Failed tasks keep processing forever

Tags: python, django

Anyone using django-q task scheduler: https://github.com/Koed00/django-q?

(Not the database related `Q` library)

I have a bunch of failed tasks. Everytime I run the django-q these failed tasks keep popping up:

```
18:06:14 [Q] INFO Process-1:9 processing [apart-sixteen-butter-friend]
18:06:14 [Q] INFO Process-1:10 processing [single-mississippi-bravo-fillet]
18:06:14 [Q] ERROR Failed [lithium-cola-batman-fanta] - No module named 'shootsta.user'
18:06:14 [Q] INFO Process-1:9 processing [ink-october-angel-california]
18:06:14 [Q] ERROR Failed [zulu-michigan-yankee-kilo] - No module named 'shootsta.user'
18:06:14 [Q] ERROR Failed [four-lemon-arizona-football] - No module named 'shootsta.user'
18:06:14 [Q] ERROR Failed [mississippi-fillet-winner-single] - No module named 'shootsta.user'
18:06:14 [Q] ERROR Failed [west-pennsylvania-asparagus-alabama] - 'BookingAnalytics' object has no attribute 'booking_uid'
18:06:14 [Q] ERROR Failed [wisconsin-pip-alanine-seventeen] - Can't switch from state 'job_complete' using method 'assign_camop'
18:06:14 [Q] ERROR Failed [finch-monkey-moon-oven] - 'AnalyticsFilter' object is not iterable
18:06:14 [Q] ERROR Failed [yellow-west-mango-papa] - 'AnalyticsFilter' object is not iterable
18:06:14 [Q] ERROR Failed [zulu-equal-mississippi-happy] - 'str' object has no attribute 'booking_uid'
18:06:14 [Q] ERROR Failed [six-beer-golf-blue] - 'str' object has no attribute 'booking_uid'
18:06:14 [Q] ERROR Failed [apart-sixteen-butter-friend] - 'str' object has no attribute 'booking_uid'
18:06:14 [Q] ERROR Failed [single-mississippi-bravo-fillet] - 'str' object has no attribute 'booking_uid'
18:06:14 [Q] ERROR Failed [ink-october-angel-california] - 'str' object has no attribute 'booking_uid'
18:06:15 [Q] ERROR reincarnated worker Process-1:4 after death
18:06:15 [Q] INFO Process-1:11 ready for work at 20244
```

The related issues mentioned in these failed tasks have been fixed. Yet the failed tasks keep showing up. Even if i remove the failed entries from database(`django_q_task` table), they are recreated every time I run the `qcluster` command.

How do I deal with this issue and stop these errors from appearing in output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is newly added configuration: `attempt_count` that you can set to 1 as per this [pull request](https://github.com/Koed00/django-q/pull/466).

`max_attempts` is not good enough and confusing - [as the minimum retries is 1](https://github.com/Koed00/django-q/issues/495) - so 2 total calls for failed tasks.

Remember you also need to set `'ack_failures': True` if an `Exception` is raised - to acknowledge the failure.

Confusing but what will work is:

```
Q_CLUSTER = {
    'name': 'DjangORM',
    'workers': 1,
    'timeout': 600,
    'orm': 'default',
    'save_limit': 0,
    'ack_failures': True,
    'max_attempts': 1,
    'attempt_count': 1
}
```

Comment: ah! what a lifesaver.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue - easiest way is to delete them via the Django admin web interface - simply log in and go to the Django Q section - delete the failed tasks - and the relevant scheduled and enqueued tasks - and that should be that.

Comment: Ya that's what I've been doing for a while. Another approach is to remove all the entries in `django_q_ormq` table if you have write access on db.

Comment: @saran3h I see - but yet they keep popping up for you because sometimes they fail.. it would be cool to have this part configurable - and/or in the docs - like until when a task will repeat - it's actually great to know that apparently the default is that it repeats itself, in case that its success is not guaranteed - e.g. relying on an external API - but it can be a pain in your case where they deterministically will always fail.
If you know of those configs and settings - LMK - maybe an issue on Github's repo..